# I am trying to build a project using maven - 'mvn clean install' but it is giving me error

Tags: java, xml, maven, cmd, repository

Project ID: org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin' not found in repository:
 Unable to download the artifact from any repository

org.codehaus.mojo:hibernate3-maven-plugin:pom:2.2

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stee.iss.iwms</groupId>
    <artifactId>oris-reports-portlet</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Oris Reports Portlet</name>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</warName>
                    <outputDirectory>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbm2java</name>
                            <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                            <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <componentProperties>
                        <revengfile>/src/main/resources/reveng/model.reveng.xml</revengfile>
                        <propertyfile>/src/main/resources/META-INF/hibernate.properties</propertyfile>
                        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                        <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                    </componentProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1_3</version>

                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>             
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources-3</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${project.basedir}/WebContent/wsdl/SSRSReport.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.stee.iss.iwms.oris.poi.powerpoint.PptxCreator</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javaassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.log4j12.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.log4j12.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${json.lib.version}</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stee.iss.iwms.oris.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>oris-common-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${iwms.oris.logger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <!-- liferay.auto.deploy.dir>d:/iwms/apps/liferay-portal-6.0.6-iwms/deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir -->
        <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>C:\Projects\PUB_IWMS\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.version>6.1.0</liferay.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javaassist.version>3.15.0-GA</javaassist.version>
        <!-- <spring.xbean.version>3.7</spring.xbean.version> -->
        <hibernate.version>3.6.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!-- <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version> -->
        <maven.war.plugin.version>2.1.1</maven.war.plugin.version>
        <json.lib.version>2.4</json.lib.version>
        <!-- <maven.compiler.plugin.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version> -->
        <slf4j.log4j12.version>1.6.1</slf4j.log4j12.version>
        <!-- <commons.codec.version>1.5</commons.codec.version> -->
        <commons.lang.version>2.6</commons.lang.version>
        <!-- <commons.beanutils.version>1.8.3</commons.beanutils.version> -->
        <!-- <commons.collections.version>3.2.1</commons.collections.version> -->
        <cxf.version>2.5.0</cxf.version>
        <exec.maven.plugin.version>1.1</exec.maven.plugin.version>      
        <iwms.oris.logger.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</iwms.oris.logger.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: did a lot of googling ,couldn't find any solution ,please help

Comment: You need to check your settings.xml usually in your home/.m2 directory.  You need to get access to the internet so you can read from maven repo.  This is usually caused by the proxy not being set.

Comment: *Unable to download*. That is pretty clear, you either don't have Internet access, or you're behind a proxy, or the think you're depending on doesn't exist.

Comment: I am connected to internet for sure ,,How to check for proxy ?and what to do if dependency does not exost

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.xml file check or put entries for

```
   settings --> proxies --> proxy,
```

if thats present put

```
    mirror entry.
```

Comment: I don't have a settings.xml in my project

Comment: it will be in %user% .m2 folder or check the Maven setting in eclipse preference.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest few immediate checks. Hopefully this will help you.

```
1) check to which artifact library you are connecting to. you must have access to the artifact library.  
 2) Try to get the plugin Manually and do mvn clean install
3) There might be an issue with eclipse itself. Do mvn clean install from cmd prompt and check.
```

Comment: I tried adding pulgin manually from cmd ,but  got same error ,also did mvn clean install always , not making build from eclipse